# How can I update my google sheet in real time using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I am importing specific tabs and headers from a Google sheet and then after some data wrangling on it using Python I am exporting it to a different google sheet. This is the code I am using for pulling all the data

```
def get_data(USS_wb,USS_sheets,USS_headers):
    USS_temp_df = []
    for sheet in USS_sheets:
        USS_df = gd.get_as_dataframe(USS_wb.worksheet(sheet),evaluate_formulas=True)
        USS_df = USS_df.reindex(USS_headers,fill_value= np.nan, axis=1)
        USS_df = USS_df[~USS_df.isna().all(axis=1)]
        USS_df['Sheet_Name'] = sheet
        USS_df['Book_Name'] = USS_wb.title
        USS_temp_df.append(USS_df)
    
    USS_data = pd.concat(USS_temp_df)
    return USS_data
```

and then I am using this code to export it to a different Google sheet

```
ws = sa.open("Exporting data").worksheet("dataset")
gd.set_with_dataframe(ws,USS_data)
```

It is all working fine for me, but I have to manually run the code to add the data from one sheet to another, how can I make it work for real time data so when a row is populated in my first google sheet, the manipulation occurs and the result is appended in my second google sheets?

Comment: Just 2 quick questions:

1)  Is there any particular reason why you are using python? If you could do the data wrangling through apps script and use triggers to automate the code

2) How is the source sheet being updated? Depending on the way the sheet is updated a trigger on Apps Script might or might not work.